# Cassandra query in java program running infinite times even though called only once

Tags: java, cassandra

I run the following code as a java program. The query runs infinite times even though it is called only once which I am not able to figure out why. It drops the keyspace during the first query and when it runs again (which it should not), it keeps giving exception numerous times that the keyspace does not exist.

What should I do to make the query run only once?

```
Session session=cassandraSessionFactory.getSession();
String query = "drop keyspace "+keyspace_name";
session.execute(query);
session.close();
```

Here is the exception stack trace which keeps on getting printed numerous times and stops only when manually halted.

```
23:24:55,654  INFO BackendOperation:75 - Temporary exception during backend operation [messageReading@0:0]. Attempting backoff retry.
com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxKeyColumnValueStore.getNamesSlice(AstyanaxKeyColumnValueStore.java:114)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxKeyColumnValueStore.getNamesSlice(AstyanaxKeyColumnValueStore.java:78)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxKeyColumnValueStore.getSlice(AstyanaxKeyColumnValueStore.java:67)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller$1.call(KCVSLog.java:769)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller$1.call(KCVSLog.java:766)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:133)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation$1.call(BackendOperation.java:147)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:56)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:42)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:144)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller.run(KCVSLog.java:703)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.BadRequestException: BadRequestException: [host=127.0.0.1(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=0(0), attempts=1]InvalidRequestException(why:Keyspace keyspace_name does not exist)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:159)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:65)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:28)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$ThriftConnection.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:153)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:119)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:352)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$4.execute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:538)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxKeyColumnValueStore.getNamesSlice(AstyanaxKeyColumnValueStore.java:112)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:Keyspace keyspace_name does not exist)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result$multiget_slice_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:14678)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result$multiget_slice_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:14633)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result.read(Cassandra.java:14559)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_multiget_slice(Cassandra.java:741)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.multiget_slice(Cassandra.java:725)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$4$1.internalExecute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:544)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$4$1.internalExecute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:541)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:60)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Well, it seems that the code is called within a loop that's _somewhere_ in the call stack. It's really hard to know where with this limited amount of code you have shared. Did you try to investigate with a debugger?

Comment: @MickMnemonic there is no loop in the code where these lines are written.

Comment: The stack trace includes a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, so maybe there are just many parallel threads running the same query. In any case, this is just guessing without knowing more about your application.

Comment: Did you close all connections to the Titan graph, i.e. `graph.close()` before dropping the keyspace? Also if you're running a Titan server, you'd probably need to shut that down before dropping the keyspace.